# Android annotation and viewpager not support

Tags: android

I am working with the android project which is having ViewPager functionality. This same code running well in other eclipse. But in my eclipse it is showing red underlines.

Here I gave my code.

```
class SwipeTickerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

        LayoutInflater mInflater;

        SwipeTickerAdapter(Context mContext) {
            mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
        }

        @Override
        public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {

            container.removeView((View) object);
        }

        @Override
        public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {

            ViewGroup pageView = (ViewGroup) mInflater.inflate(
                    mLayoutsticker[position], container, false);
            TextView b = (TextView) pageView.getChildAt(0);

            try {
                b.setText(annoncement_data.get(position * 2));
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    int val = mTickerpager.getCurrentItem();
                    System.out.println("Clicked current item is ---" + val
                            + "&&&&&&&&&&" + annoncement_data.get(val * 2 + 1));
                    Resulttickettouch = annoncement_data.get(val * 2);

                    ArrayList<String> tickerSelectedValue = new ArrayList<String>();
                    tickerSelectedValue.add(annoncement_data.get(val * 2));
                    tickerSelectedValue.add(annoncement_data.get(val * 2 + 1));
                    startActivity(new Intent(mContext, HomeTickerPicker.class)
                            .putExtra("TickerValues", tickerSelectedValue));
                    ticket_ShowDialog();

                    // DemoPopupWindow dw = new DemoPopupWindow(v);
                    // dw.showLikeQuickAction(0, 30);
                }
            });

            container.addView(pageView);
            return pageView;

        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return legthticketview;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object obj) {
            return view == obj;
        }

    }
```

The above code ask me to remove @override at destroyItems and InstantiateItems, If I remove the override line  then again ask me to add unimplemented methods. And also showing the error line in import android.annotation.TargetApi;

Help me to solve.

Comment: Hi I also see those type of issues. But here it seems like version level issue.